# Is there a way to change the Print Preview GUI that comes up when printing a page from Microsoft Edge?

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-edge

I am wondering if there is a way to change the print preview page that comes up when printing from Microsoft Edge (V 44.17763.771.0). I would love it if the dialogue could be changed to show the old Microsoft Internet Explorer Print Preview page, instead of the page that comes up (I have a Toshiba printer, so it brings up the Toshiba Print dialogue.) I'm new when it comes to this kind of thing, but I'm very interested and ready to learn, so please let me know what my options are.

Comment: You should ask on [su]

Answer (score 0):

There's no such way to change Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML) print dialogue into the style like Internet Explorer. This is due to the browser design. The print preview dialogue in Edge is like below and you could change the options in it as you wish. You could also refer to [this article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-print-edge-windows-10) about detailed information of print settings in Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML):

[image]